# Error doing npm install on react reduction

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I downloaded the react reduction project from github and tried to npm install

I got a bunch of verbose that I couldn't make anything out of. I just downloaded the github project with git bash and opened it in vs code, opened a terminal and typed npm install and I keep getting that. I tried yarn install.. same thing

Here's the the log

```
PS D:\React\react-reduction> npm install
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: recompose@0.22.0
npm WARN Found: react@16.8.4
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^16.8.4" from the root project
npm WARN   16 more (react-chartjs-2, react-component-queries, react-dom, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0" from recompose@0.22.0
npm WARN node_modules/recompose
npm WARN   recompose@"^0.22.0" from react-infinite-calendar@2.3.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-infinite-calendar
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@15.7.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0" from recompose@0.22.0
npm WARN   node_modules/recompose
npm WARN     recompose@"^0.22.0" from react-infinite-calendar@2.3.1
npm WARN     node_modules/react-infinite-calendar
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.2.0
npm WARN Found: @babel/core@7.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions/node_modules/@babel/core
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @babel/core@"^7.0.0-0" from @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions
npm WARN   @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@"^7.2.0" from @babel/preset-env@7.3.1
npm WARN   node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.3.4
npm WARN Found: @babel/core@7.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/node_modules/@babel/core
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @babel/core@"^7.0.0-0" from @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
npm WARN   @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@"^7.3.1" from @babel/preset-env@7.3.1
npm WARN   node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.3.4
npm WARN Found: @babel/core@7.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/node_modules/@babel/core
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @babel/core@"^7.0.0-0" from @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes
npm WARN   @babel/plugin-transform-classes@"^7.2.0" from @babel/preset-env@7.3.1
npm WARN   node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/preset-env
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\MOUDHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall65755735747.cmd
npm ERR! Building: D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\React\\react-reduction\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\Moudhaffer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Moudhaffer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];     
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:399:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\React\\react-reduction\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\React\react-reduction\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Any kind of help please?

Comment: Not an expert here in NPM, but having python2 which is somehow no longer supported is strange. Are you sure you downloaded the latest version of this github project?

Comment: Yes, I mean the project in itself is a bit old.. Last push was 2019 so that's where I'm guessing this issue is coming from.